# How to delete / drop multiple tables in AWS athena?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I am trying to drop few tables from Athena and I cannot run multiple DROP queries at same time. Is there a way to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: Please check [how to ask question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) 
Add your code , what have you tried.

Answer (score 14):

You can use [aws-cli `batch-delete-table`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/glue/batch-delete-table.html) to delete multiple table at once.

```
aws glue batch-delete-table \
--database-name <database-name> \
--tables-to-delete "<table1-name>" "<table2-name>" "<table3-name>" ...
```

Comment: This is equivalent to: Glue console > Tables > (search view) select all matching tables > Action > Delete

Answer (score 11):

You are correct. It is not possible to run multiple queries in the one request.

An alternative is to create the tables in a specific database. Dropping the database will then cause all the tables to be deleted.

For example:

```
CREATE DATABASE foo;
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE bar1 ...;
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE bar2 ...;
DROP DATABASE foo CASCADE;
```

The `DROP DATABASE` command will delete the `bar1` and `bar2` tables.

Answer (score 7):

You can use AWS Glue interface to do this now. The prerequisite being you must upgrade to AWS Glue Data Catalog.

If you Upgrade to the AWS Glue Data Catalog from Athena, the metadata for tables created in Athena is visible in Glue and you can use the AWS Glue UI to check multiple tables and delete them at once.

FAQ on Upgrading data catalog: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/glue-faq.html

Answer (score 4):

You could write a shell script to do this for you:

```
for table in products customers stores; do 
    aws athena start-query-execution --query-string "drop table $table" --result-configuration OutputLocation=s3://my-ouput-result-bucket
done
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [AWS Glue](https://aws.amazon.com/glue/)'s [Python shell](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/01/introducing-python-shell-jobs-in-aws-glue/) and  invoke this function:

```py
    def run_query(query, database, s3_output):
        client = boto3.client('athena')
        response = client.start_query_execution(
            QueryString=query,
            QueryExecutionContext={
                'Database': database
                },
            ResultConfiguration={
                'OutputLocation': s3_output,
                }
            )
        print('Execution ID: ' + response['QueryExecutionId'])
        return response
```

Athena configuration:

```py
    s3_input = 's3://athena-how-to/data'
    s3_ouput = 's3://athena-how-to/results/'
    database = 'your_database'
    table = 'tableToDelete'
    query_1 = "drop table %s.%s;" % (database, table)
    queries = [ query_1]
    #queries = [ create_database, create_table, query_1, query_2 ]
    for q in queries:
       print("Executing query: %s" % (q))
       res = run_query(q, database, s3_ouput)
```

Answer (score 1):

@Vidy

I would second what @Prateek said.  Please provide an example of your code.  Also, please tag your post with the language/shell that you're using to interact with AWS.

Currently, you cannot run multiple queries in one request.  However, you can make multiple requests simultaneously.  Currently, you can run 20 requests simultaneously (2018-06-15).  You could do this through an API call or the console.   In addition you could use the [CLI](https://aws.amazon.com/cli) or the [SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/tools/) (if available for your language of choice).

For example, in Python you could use the multiprocess or threading modules to manage concurrent requests.  Just remember to [consider thread/multiprocess safety](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/resources.html) when creating resources/clients.

**Service Limits:**

[Athena Service Limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/service-limits.html)

[AWS Service Limits for which you can request a rate increase](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws_service_limits.html)

Answer (score 0):

I could not get Carl's method to work by executing DROP TABLE statements even though they did work in the console.

So I just thought it was worth posting my approach that worked for me, which uses a combination of the AWS Pandas SDK and the CLI

```
import awswrangler as wr
import boto3
import os

 session = boto3.Session(
     aws_access_key_id='XXXXXX',
     aws_secret_access_key='XXXXXX',
     aws_session_token='XXXXXX'
)

database_name = 'athena_db'
athena_s3_output = 's3://athena_s3_bucket/athena_queries/'

df = wr.athena.read_sql_query(
    sql= "SELECT DISTINCT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE 
table_schema = '" + database_name + "'",
    database= database_name,
    s3_output = athena_s3_output,
    boto3_session = session
)

print(df)

# ensure that your aws profile is valid for CLI commands
# i.e. your credentials are set in C:\Users\xxxxxxxx\.aws\credentials

for table in df['table_name']:
    cli_string = 'aws glue delete-table --database-name ' + database_name + ' --name ' + table
    print(cli_string)
    os.system(cli_string)
```